# Interfaces exposing generic overload. How to DRY here?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

I have this interface

```
interface IMyInterface 
{
    object Create(Type t);
}
```

For convenience, I would also include a generic overload that wraps a call to the method, so it becomes:

```
interface IMyInterface 
{
    object Create(Type t);
    T Create<T>();
}
```

The new method would be implemented like this

```
public object Create<T>()  
{
    return (T) Create(typeof(T)); 
}
```

The problem of the approach:

- If **I include** the overload in the interface, then I'm forcing
  implementors to have a silly wrapper method that is always THE
  SAME.
- If **I don't include** the overload, the ability to call is lost when using a reference to `IMyInteface`

How do I solve this design issue?

Comment: Use abstract class instead

Comment: An abstract class may be a solution, but it's not an option here. It would restrict users in another way, and that's what I don't want.

Comment: Why wouldn't `Create<T>` return a `T` instead of an `object`?

Comment: D Stanley: Cool! Edited the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best solution would be to use an extension method:

```
public static MyInterfaceExtensions
{
    public T Create<T>(this IMyInterface target)  
    {
        return (T) target.Create(typeof(T)); 
    }
}
```

The extension method can then be called just as a regular method.